# sonarQube execution failed with “Error during SonarQube Scanner execution”

Tags: sonarqube

We are using SonarQube for code analysis. Our projects are developed using C# and gitlab CI build pipeline.

Command used to scan the code:

```
dotnet sonarscanner begin /k:xxxxxx
/d:sonar.host.url=https://sonar.xxxxx.com/ /d:sonar.login=<<login id>> /d:sonar.verbose=true /d:sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths="tmp/xx/testresults/coverage.opencover.xml" /d:sonar.coverage.exclusions="*Tests.cs,*Integration.cs" - .
```

Now job failing with below error:

```
10:46:41.660 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
10:46:41.660 ERROR: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.report.ActiveRulesPublisher
10:46:41.660 ERROR: Caused by: Unable to load component interface org.sonar.api.batch.rule.ActiveRules
10:46:41.660 ERROR: Caused by: Failed to load quality profiles
10:46:41.661 ERROR: Caused by: timeout
10:46:41.661 ERROR:
```

Any Idea what can be wrong?

Comment: Try this fix: Stop the SonarQube server, remove the data/es folder and restart SonarQube again.